# What's the correct way to authenticate a user without PAM?

Tags: linux, password, authentication, pam, shadow

as my related question doesn't seem to get much love, here another one:
**What's the proper way to authenticate a user via username/password prompt in Linux nowadays?**

In principle, I suppose I would have to obtain username and password, read salt and hash of the corresponding user from `/etc/shadow`. I would then calculate the hash of the given password and the stored salt and check if the result matches the hash stored in `/etc/shadow`.

Normally, I could simply authenticate via PAM (e.g. `pam_unix`) which does all this already but my application is a custom PAM module and I found no method to call one PAM module from another. If this is possible somehow, I'd gladly go for this solution.

As of now, I found this really dated tutorial http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Shadow-Password-HOWTO-8.html from 1996 when, apparently, shadow support was not yet built into libc. It mentions `pw_auth` and `valid` as helper functions for authentication. I tried implanting these into my code and linking against `libshadow.a` of the shadow-tools but I get 'unresolved external reference' errors for `pw_auth` and `valid`. The code looks something like this:

```
if ((pw->pw_passwd && pw->pw_passwd[0] == '@'
     && pw_auth (pw->pw_passwd+1, pw->pw_name, PW_LOGIN, NULL))
    || !valid (passwd, pw)) {
    return (UPAP_AUTHNAK);
}
```

I haven't checked this further but anyway this is not a preferred solution as I'd have to update my code every time shadow-utils are updated.

I'd much rather link to a library (that isn't PAM) that provides authentication against `/etc/shadow`. Is there such thing and I didn't find it yet? Or some other solution?

Comment: The normal way to do what you describe would be to leave username/password authentication out of your module, and stack it after `pam_unix` (and `pam_ldap`).

Comment: I still want to be able to execute commands after the user has successfully authenticated themself. At first start, my module should detect that the user has not logged in previously, require an authentication and create my custom token afterwards. From the second login on I would not require `pam_unix` anymore (except when my module fails).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You fear of an update of shadow-utils is IMO unwarranted. The routines described in that HOWTO are available on my Ubuntu 12.04 and Mint 17 systems without installing anything special.

The structure to read `/etc/shadow` information in a C program can be found in `/usr/include/shadow.h` and with `man 5 shadow` and the functions that you would need to find e.g. a shadow password entry by name as defined in `/usr/include/shadow.h` is `getspnam` and that will get you a man page as well (`man getspnam`) describing that and all related functions.

Based on that you should be able to get the hashed password entry for any given name. The hashed password should have multiple '$' tokens, cut of everything after and including the last '$' from the hashed password and present that as salt to `crypt()`, the glibc version (according to `man 3 crypt`) should be able to handle the "extended" salts that indicate SHA512 entries as are more common nowadays.

Comment: Ok, so doing the authentication myself via `crypt()` and `getspnam` should be doable. Are `pw_auth` and `valid` also available in your installation? Because I can't find them on my Ubuntu 14.04 (only when installing shadow-tools from source and linking to the library and even then it does not work)

They don't do very much actually and I could replace them with my own code of course - I am just curious as to why they have been dropped.

Comment: Another thing that came to mind: What method should be used to prompt the user for a password? Is there an availabe function/library that does this for me (providing the standard system password entry prompt)?

Comment: @SonnyO'Rullivan No `pwauth.h` is not installed. You should just compare the output from crypt with the shadow entry (not sure if you have to prepend the salt yourself). For the password prompt I would look at what `login` does, IIRC it just switches of echoing, but it has been a long time since I looked at that.

Comment: Thanks, tried `crypt()` after obtaining salt and hash type and it worked nicely. Easier than I had thought and I don't even need `pwauth.h` etc. The login part should not be too much effort then as well.